# How to use the 'Issue attribute path' in the parameter mapping of jenkins-trigger-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-jira-trigger

I am willing to trigger my Jenkins job based on status change event from a JIRA issue. I am able to do it using jenkins-trigger-plugin. However I wish to get some more information about the issue like the description of the issue etc. I could see an environment variable named 'JIRA_ISSUE_KEY' but it gives me the key and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current release, the `issue attribute path` is currently resolved from [this `Issue` object](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-api/2.0.0-m31/jira-rest-java-client-api/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/domain/Issue.html). All of jira-trigger-plugin configuration is documented in [Jenkins help buttons](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/ceilfors/jenkins/plugins/jiratrigger/parameter/IssueAttributePathParameterMapping/help.html), which is viewable in Jenkins job configuration.

`description` for example is retrievable via `description` path (which would call `issue.getDescription()` essentially).

Comment: I used the `description path` and got the description of the task present in Jira. However after some time my build continued to trigger but the  environment variable returns blank value. I have not made any changes since it worked fine. It still resolved other environment variables including JIRA_ISSUE_KEY but not the one I defined using 'Issue attribute path'.

Comment: Sounds like either a bug or JIRA webhook is not behaving as expected i.e. the description is not being sent over. Please file a bug in JIRA complete with the debugging log enabled.

Comment: I have logged an issue [39766](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39766). Please let me know if more details are required.