# Jira Trigger plugin for Jenkins: Obtaining Value from issue object

Tags: jenkins-jira-trigger

I'm trying to set up some automation using Jenkins and Jira Trigger plugin for Jenkins. I've set up a web hook at Jira side which is able to invoke build on Jenkins as desired.

I've a trouble with obtaining value for a custom field from incoming Jira request.

I'm trying to use "Issue Attribute Path" feature and I've also referred to post ([How to use the 'Issue attribute path' in the parameter mapping of jenkins-trigger-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590979/how-to-use-the-issue-attribute-path-in-the-parameter-mapping-of-jenkins-trigge))

Howevevr I'm still unable to get value for custom fields `customfield_10010`, `customfield_10011`. I've tried with mapping like `fields.customfield_10010`, `fields.customfield_10010.value`, `fields.customfield_10010.0.value`,`customfield_10010.0.value` and similar combinations. I'm able to get value for other standard fields as suggested in plugin help. ex: `status.name`, `description` etc.

I could not get any clue from [Jira documentation site](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-api/2.0.0-m31/jira-rest-java-client-api/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/domain/Issue.html) either.

Parts of incoming json data is below for easy reference.

```
  "issue": {
            "id": "1000x",
            "self": "http://localhost:3080/rest/api/2/issue/10007",
            "key": "ABC-2",
            "fields": {
                "issuetype": {
                    ..
                },
                "parent": {
                    ..
                },
                "components": [

            ],
            "timespent": null,
            "timeoriginalestimate": 28800,
            "description": ".....",
            "project": {
                ..
            },
            "customfield_10010": [
                {
                    "self": "http://localhost:3080/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10019",
                    "value": "ABC-Custom 1",
                    "id": "10019"
                }
            ],
            "fixVersions": [

            ],
            "customfield_10011": [
                {
                    "self": "http://localhost:3080/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10021",
                    "value": "ABC-Custom 2",
                    "id": "10021"
                }
            ],
            .....
            ....
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not an implemented feature. See: [JENKINS-38797](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of a custom field with the following syntax:

```
fields.find { it.id == "customfield_10010" }.value
```

I had the same problem and found this solution here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13216

Comment: Your link seems to go else where. I found your workaround here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38797?focusedCommentId=291365&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-291365